# How to set http request body using Spring RestTemplate execute?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, get, spring-3, resttemplate

I'd like to use *RestTemplate* to issue requests. I must send a request payload with a GET request. Yeah-yeah, I know. So I tried *RestTemplate.exchange*, but it seems it is not sending the payload for GET requests, no matter what. So I looked further in the docs and figures *RestTemplate.execute* might be what I am looking for ... and now here I am.

So the doc states about *execute*:

> Execute the HTTP method to the given URI template, preparing the request with the *RequestCallback*, and reading the response with a *ResponseExtractor*.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html

Okay. Let's see *RequestCallback*

> Callback interface for code that operates on a *ClientHttpRequest*. Allows to manipulate the request headers, and write to the request body. 
>   Used internally by the *RestTemplate*, but also useful for application code.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RequestCallback.html

But *RequestCallback* has one method only: *doWithRequest*, which accepts it's parameter through the *ClientHttpRequest* interface... which has no methods for setting/manipulating the body of the request. Sadly. :C

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequest.html

So, I have two questions:

- What am I missing here regarding the docs?
- How can I issue a GET request with a payload/request body using RestTemplate?

Comment: *Yeah-yeah, I know*: then why are you doing it? GET requests are not supposed to have a payload. That said, ClientHttpRequest has a getBody() method. So, what's the problem?

Comment: "Yeah-yeah, I know."

Any helpful idea would be nice though!

Comment: How did you go with this? I need to stub the connection to a server and replace it with a static a restTemplate. I need the request to use the predefined restTemplate and sends the response to the application during component testing.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
public class BodySettingRequestCallback implements RequestCallback {

    private String body;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public BodySettingRequestCallback(String body, ObjectMapper objectMapper){
        this.body = body;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
      byte[] json = getEventBytes();
      request.getBody().write(json);
    }

    byte[] getEventBytes() throws JsonProcessingException {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(body);
    }
}
```

You are going to use this RequestCallback in your execute method. Something like:

```
restTemplate.execute(url, HttpMethod.POST, callback, responseExtractor);
```

Comment: what is mapper here?

Comment: Good catch, it is an ObjectMapper. Will edit. Thanks.